# Sit in for(is it common?)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sit-in-for

> to take the place of someone temporarily
>
> > **I’ll be sitting in for the secretary at/on the meeting tonight.**

Is the use of "sit in for" common or is this one used more:

> He's taking place of her for a day.

Which one is used more "sit in for" or "take somebody's place"(temporary)? And can "on" be used instead of "at" for the meeting? **I'll be sitting in for the secretary on the meeting.**

Comment: Not quite sure of what the problem is here.  You have an expression and an example of its use.  The dictionary tells you to use "at the meeting". And the dictionary tells you the meaning of "sitting in for".  You have an alternative (that you have have incorrectly re-ordered from the dictionary example.  ("take her place", not "take place of her" )  I would do what the dictionary says.  You can use "sitting in for" in this context but the preposition is "at".

Comment: So @James K what's more commonly used? "Take place" or "sit in for"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would rephrase "He's taking place of her for a day" to:

> He's taking **her place** (at the meeting) for a day.

To preserve "place of her" the sentence could be phrased as:

> He will be at the meeting **in place of her**.

According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) "sit in for" is more common in American English than in British English, but not by much.

Comment: So what would be more common "sit in for" or "take her place"? What will most likely be used by the natives???

Comment: "Sit in for" is definitely more likely, especially in a situation where there is actual sitting going on (like a meeting).